# Render not reflecting changes made in video editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am making a video project and what I am trying to do is cut out a bunch of segments from a video. I was able to cut the segments out realign them and in the preview window everything is as I want, however when I go to export the video exports without any of my changes being shown
[image: this is what the time line of my picture looks like]

this is what the time line of my picture looks like
if there is anything else I can do to help I am happy to share more relevant details if needed
thank you